# How does CockroachDB sync/replicate data between nodes?

Tags: cockroachdb

Because it’s a distributed database, how does CockroachDB ensure that each node has access to the same data that all of the others do?

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB uses Raft (a consensus algorithm) to synchronize data across all nodes that host a range of data. For more detail, CockroachDB has a blog post about how they've made that work here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/consensus-made-thrive/